# Can you identify the construction material/system used in the pic?

Tags: frame, identification

What's the name of the "big meccano" used in the photo below to construct all the cabinets and racks?

It appears to be an aluminium cut-to-length system of 4-way rails. I've seen it used many times and assume it has a well-known brand-name to those that know.

[image: Inside Audi facility]

Photo taken from theverge.com and was a feature about how Audi are building a new car.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like 80/20 to me: http://www.8020.net/

I've used it many times...pretty useful stuff.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much. So it's known as "T-slot framing" in the industry and there appear to be a few good makers internationally. Cool.

Comment: As @LukePuplett says there are many other vendors, e.g.: http://www13.boschrexroth-us.com/framing_shop/

Comment: +1 for directly answering the question. You might also mention that the horizontal rails are [DIN rail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_rail), and people making smaller robots might want to look at [miniature T-slot rails](http://reprap.org/wiki/T-Slot) -- OpenRail, VSlot, MakerBeam, OpenBeam.

Answer (score 3):

The original T-slot frame system, was developed in the 80's by [item GmbH](http://www.item24.de/en.html) and was quickly developed into the [*MB Building Kit System*](http://catalog.item24us.com/en/index.php?cat=c1001009411_MB-Building-Kit-for-Mechanical-Engineering.html), hence I've always known it as *item bar*.

Since then though, there have been many other manufacturers producing similar systems. Examples include [Bosch Rexroth](http://www13.boschrexroth-us.com/framing_shop/) (as mentioned by [Guy Sirton](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/1584/guy-sirton)), [80/20](http://www.8020.net/) ([Andrew Capodieci's suggestion](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/2886/37)), [FlexLink](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/b/flexlink/) and many others, but *item* is still one of the most popular and well respected, especially in Europe.

Also, as [David Cary](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/187/david-cary) says there are also people producing micro versions of T-slot systems, such as [OpenRail/VSlot](http://openbuildspartstore.com/v-slot/?sort=featured), [MakerBeam](http://www.makerbeam.eu/) and [OpenBeam](http://www.openbeamusa.com/) etc.